# Only use metric space and continuous map to describe homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My friend had read some popular science readings about topology. He knows two objects are said to be homeomorphic if there is a continuous deformation from one to another. Doughnut and coffee cup are the same in topologist's eyes.

He asked me the real math under the statement. When I explain the mathematical concepts of topology to him, like open sets, continues maps, metric spaces and so on, he raised this question.

Can we only use the metric space and the continues maps to describe that two things are homeomorphic. Why do we still need the concept of topological space?

For example, we can use the points in the metric space of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to describe a doughnut, and also a cup. If we can find a continuous map between the two (the inverse is also continues), then we can say that the two are the same topology. This has already used a relatively rigorous statement to describe what the popular science readings said.

I cannot give a good answer, and I want to ask: what is the most important reason that this is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

*If* those two things that are homeomorphic are metric spaces, then, yes, there is no need to consider topological spaces here. However, those two things might not be metric spaces. For instance, the spaces $(\Bbb R,\tau_l)$ and $(\Bbb R,\tau_r)$, where $\tau_l$ is the topology spanned by the intervals of the form $(a,b]$ and $\tau_r$ is the topology spanned by the intervals of the form $[a,b)$, are homeomorphic. And neither of them is metrizable.

Comment: Thanks! This is my thought about your answer. Almost every example from topology book for amateur math enthusiast are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So it is fine to think it only in metric space. However, mathematicians found a weaker structure called topological space. And in topological space, we can still study continuous maps. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, except that I would not say that a topology is a weaker structure than a metric. I would rather say that the concept of topological spaces is more general than the concept of metric space.

Comment: Yes, 'general' is more appropriate here.